# Issues With Double Insert MYSQLI

Tags: insert, mysqli

Are you allowed to do something like this with mysqli? I'm getting nothing going in.

```
// Place the transaction into the database   
   $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, ip, username)       
       VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee','$ip','$user_name')";
       $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx); 
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO courseprogress (id, product_id_array, email, username) VALUES ('$uid','$custom','$payer_email','$username')";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
   //
```

I've tried to use two separate statements like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, ip, username)       
       VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee','$ip','$user_name')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
//added as addition for newsletter signup below
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx); 
            $sqlemail = "INSERT INTO courseprogress (id, product_id_array, email,username) VALUES ('$uid','$custom','$payer_email','$username')";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlemail);
   //
```

I've only been able to get the first to go through though on the lower attempt...Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks ok. What's the error you get from the second query in that case? Check the results for errors. Also, you're most likely vulnerable to SQL injection. Make sure your strings are properly escaped or (even better) use parametrised statements instead.

Comment: @viraptor thanks for the info...my problem is the script that contains this is not run when a visit to a page occurs. It happens off my site(not technically). It is part of an IPN where as a user pays at paypal it fires off. So I can't get to the errors unless it is the php itself...no the mysqli statemtns. All I know is the second statment is not inserted.

Comment: you can turn on error and warning logging in your php.ini. Whether you run the script via cli or web server (I don't understand which case you mean), any issues will be logged. Alternatively you can log the error yourself. Check if the result of `mysqli_query(...)` is === FALSE. If it is, print/log the result of http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - that will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @viraptor can you give me an example of what you mean? I'm not understanding the reference link you sent.

Comment: @viraptor is it something like this?  `if (!$mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}`

Is there a way to print it to another page? As I said the page isn't a page that can be opened manually. It must be triggered by paypal and I never see it.

Comment: You have to figure out a way to call it without paypal. For example set some variable that feeds it test data instead of real one. If you cannot run that process yourself, you will not be able to debug it in the future. Also, in a typical php installation sending a message to http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php will most likely cause it to go to your configured error_log file.

Answer (score 0):

you have the $db_conx data in the wrong place, it need to be in the same statement.
Did you upgrade the sql?...i did it, and i had to refigure out the whole project i had created.
Create a function that holds the data or global the data and redeclare the $db_conx every time your in a statement or function.